# Android MediaPlayer release() освободить память от MediaPlayer

Tags: mediaplayer, android

Не могу понять как правильно освободить память от MediaPlayer при нажатии onBackPressed если плеер играет

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class SingleMenuItemActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener{
    private Button btn_play, btn_pause, btn_stop;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int lengthOfAudio;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    // XML node keys
    static final String login = "login";
    static final String pass = "pass";
    static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    static final String KEY_FROM = "from_";
    static final String KEY_TO = "to_";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    //static final String KEY_TYPEMSG = "typeMsg";
    static final String KEY_FILENAME = "filename";
    private final String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/idev.sedek.ekeymangorecords/cache/";
    String filename,data,errorcode;
    int data1;
    int downloadedSize = 0;
    int totalSize = 0;
    int kilobytes = 0;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private final Runnable r = new Runnable() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekProgress();                   
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
        btn_play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        btn_play.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
        btn_pause.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
        btn_stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        btn_stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
        seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekBar.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();
        // Get XML values from previous intent
        String date = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DATE);
        String from_ = in.getStringExtra(KEY_FROM);
        String to_ = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TO);
        String duration = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);
        //String typeMsg = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TYPEMSG);
        final String filename = in.getStringExtra(KEY_FILENAME);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lbldate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_label);
        TextView lblfrom_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.from__label);
        TextView lblto_ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.to__label);
        TextView lblduration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.duration_label);
        //TextView lbltypeMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.typeMsg_label);
        TextView lblfilename = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filename_label);

        lbldate.setText(date);
        lblfrom_.setText(from_);
        lblto_.setText(to_);
        lblduration.setText(duration);
        //lbltypeMsg.setText(typeMsg);
        lblfilename.setText(filename);

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> ast = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pd = new ProgressDialog(SingleMenuItemActivity.this);
                pd.setTitle("Загрузка файла");
                pd.setMessage("Ждите...");
                pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pd.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getFile();

                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pd.dismiss();
                try {
                    Intent in = getIntent();
                    String filename = in.getStringExtra(KEY_FILENAME);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(PATH+filename);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    lengthOfAudio = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        };
        ast.execute();
    }
    public void getFile() {
        Intent in = getIntent();
        String filename = in.getStringExtra(KEY_FILENAME);
        String login1 = in.getStringExtra(login);
        String pass1 = in.getStringExtra(pass);
        try{
            String AUDIO_PATH = "http://92.75.25.212:8080/imap/attachments/"+filename;
            AUDIO_PATH = AUDIO_PATH.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            String username = login1;
            String password = pass1;
            String userpassword = username + ":" + password;
            URL url = new URL(AUDIO_PATH);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            String encoded = new String(Base64.encode(userpassword.getBytes(),Base64.NO_CLOSE));
            c.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
            c.connect();

            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            String fileName = filename;
            File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
            totalSize = c.getContentLength();
            kilobytes = totalSize / 1024;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pd.setMax(kilobytes);

                    TextView fileSizeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fileSizeView);
                    fileSizeView.setText(String.valueOf(kilobytes));
                }               
            });

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;

            while ( (bufferLength = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                final int downloadedSize1 = downloadedSize / 1024; //Kilobytes
                // update the progressbar //
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pd.setProgress(downloadedSize1);
                        float per = ((float)downloadedSize1/kilobytes) * 100;
                        pd.setMessage("Загрузка " + downloadedSize1 + "KB из " + kilobytes + "KB (" + (int)per + "%)" );
                    }
                });
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int percent) {
        seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        btn_play.setEnabled(true);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            SeekBar tmpSeekBar = (SeekBar)v;
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((lengthOfAudio / 100) * tmpSeekBar.getProgress() );
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_play:
            playAudio();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_pause:
            pauseAudio();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_stop:
            stopAudio();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        updateSeekProgress();
    }

    private void updateSeekProgress() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            seekBar.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / lengthOfAudio) * 100));
            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
        }
    }

    private void stopAudio() {
        //  mediaPlayer.stop();
        try {
            Intent in = getIntent();
            String filename = in.getStringExtra(KEY_FILENAME);
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(PATH+filename);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        btn_play.setEnabled(true);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(false);
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    private void pauseAudio() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        btn_play.setEnabled(true);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void playAudio() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        btn_play.setEnabled(false);
        btn_pause.setEnabled(true);
        btn_stop.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();

        mediaPlayer.release();

        super.onBackPressed();//выдаёт ошибку  
    }
}
```

Стэктрэйс исключения:

```
11-11 12:25:11.209: W/dalvikvm(13875): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a52700)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875): java.lang.IllegalStateException
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at idev.sedek.ekeymangorecords.SingleMenuItemActivity.updateSeekProgress(SingleMenuItemActivity.java:247)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at idev.sedek.ekeymangorecords.SingleMenuItemActivity.access$0(SingleMenuItemActivity.java:246)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at idev.sedek.ekeymangorecords.SingleMenuItemActivity$1.run(SingleMenuItemActivity.java:57)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-11 12:25:11.209: E/AndroidRuntime(13875):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Несомненно, мы сами догадаемся, какая у вас возникает ошибка. А ежели усердно будем медитировать, то и стектрейс — не проблема. А вы не беспокойтесь, просто ждите. Незачем ведь утруждать себя, предоставляя необходимые сведения.

Comment: Простите, я не отправлял текст сообщения, просто отошёл, естественно я бы без лога не отправил.
Извините ещё раз, добавил текст лога с ошибкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему вы решили, что исключение возникает на отмеченной вами строке? Судя по стэктрейсу, оно возникает на 247 строке в методе `updateSeekProgress()`, что, скорее всего, строка с условием `if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) …`.

И причина этого проста — `updateSeekProgress()` продолжает вызываться после `mediaPlayer.release();` в `onBackPressed()`.

А как гласит [документация](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying()) на метод `MediaPlayer.isPlaying()`:

> **Throws IllegalStateException if the internal player engine** has not been initialized or **has been released**.